# Unity crashes Suddenly

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, package-managers

I used unity a long time and suddenly it started to crash (on every unity version). My upm.log:

```
[2021-01-24T13:16:36.882Z][INFO] Creating server instance

[2021-01-24T13:16:36.932Z][INFO] Starting Server

[2021-01-24T13:16:36.946Z][INFO] Server started on port [65174]

[2021-01-24T13:16:37.254Z][INFO] Health Request received

[2021-01-24T13:18:52.909Z][ERROR] [Unity Package Manager (Upm)]

Parent process [18192] was terminated
```

I tried to log out and log in again, i tried to make a new inbound in the firewall but it didnt helped.

I hope u can help me

Answer (score 0):

Did you use vaccine?

If so try uncheck unity folder and work folder. (DMZ)

Sometimes Vaccine has security issues.